# How to get text from a textbox in react native without using onchangeText?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-textinput

I have already set a default value in a text box

```
<TextInput style={styles.textName} defaultValue={array.name} onChangeText={(name)=>this.setState({name})}/>
```

It's a part of a form that I created the form is already filled with default values the user can edit only the he/she wants and when he submits the form all the data will be added to another array. 
But with the current code only the text boxes that user edit will be added to the new array because of onChangeText. How can I get the text in the text box without onChangeText

Comment: You can get the text from `this.state.name` because you have `setState({name})`

Comment: And if you want to get something showed on text box, just get the data same as how your data from at text tag?

Comment: Add this prop `value={this.state.name}` to your TextInput

Comment: Try to use onBlur() of TextInput

Comment: Can you pass the whole thing? I think here is not the problem